# .animate jquery method not working

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I am using the [Foundation 4 framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/) for a simple page I am developing. I need to automatically scroll to a position on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log('Ready...'); // Does work

    $('html, body').animate({ // Doesn't work
        scrollTop: 1000
    }, 2000);

});
```

This animation doesn't work. It gives no errors but the `console.log` does work.

As per the Foundation template the jQuery gets loaded at the bottom of the page:

```
    <script>
        document.write('<script src=' +
                ('__proto__' in {} ? 'javascripts/vendor/zepto' : 'javascripts/vendor/jquery') +
                '.js><\/script>')
    </script>
```

Why wouldn't my `.animate` method work? Other jquery code works.

UPDATE:

Instead of adding the above `document.write` code (as per Foundation 4 template), if I add jquery normally: `<script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery.js"></script>` it all works. Strange.

Comment: First: Did you try any other jQuery commands? Second: Did you try any other animations? Third: Did you try scrolling an element that isn't the body?

Comment: Alone it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6bhU3/. Checked the console for errors?

Comment: yes I tried `on.('click')` commands which worked fine. There are no errors in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered this page: http://zurb.com/article/1180/how-to-use-foundation-4-s-faster-better-a that explains that Foundation 4 actually uses Zepto, which uses the same syntax as jQuery hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DKvls

```
console.log();
```

is not a jQuery feature so it will work regardless of if you have jQuery or not.
Make sure your jQuery is loaded before your script otherwise it won't work.

Comment: the `console.log()` line is to prove there are no errors when using `$(document).ready` and that jquery is getting loaded.